# Como puedo najar datos de un usuario en sesión?

Tags: php, registro

Hola estoy creando una pagina que registre mascotas en PHP, ya llevo avances como el login, el registro, la sesión el y muestra datos del usuario.

Mi problema es que tengo en la base de datos una primare key en la tabla propietarios que es el idpropietario y en la tabla mascotas una foreing asociada al idpropietarios, y al hacer que se me listen todas las mascotas de el usuario en sesion me baja todas las mascotas registradas incluyendo las de otros usuarios

Codigo cabecera

```
<?php
include("conexion.php");

// inicia una session
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['id_usuario'])) {
  header("location: index.php");
}

//consulta funcionando

$iduser = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
//$sql = "SELECT idpropietarios, p_nombres, p_tel, p_callenumero, p_colonia, ciudad, p_estado FROM propietarios WHERE p_email = '$iduser'";
//prueba consulta amplia

$sql = "SELECT Pro.idpropietarios, Pro.p_nombres, Pro.p_tel, Pro.p_callenumero, Pro.p_colonia, Pro.ciudad, Pro.p_estado, Mas.m_nombre, Mas.m_nac, Mas.m_rasgos, Mas.m_enfermedades, Mas.m_habitos FROM propietarios Pro, mascotas Mas WHERE p_email = '$iduser'";

$resultado = $conexion->query($sql);
$row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();

//registro de nueva mascota ventana modal

if (isset($_POST["registrarm"])) {
  $mnombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['mnombre']);
  $mnacimiento = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['mnac']);
  $mrasgos = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['mrasgos']);
  $menfermedades = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['menfermedades']);
  $mhabitos = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['mhabitos']);
  $idprop = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['idprop']);
  $sqluser = "SELECT p_email FROM propietarios WHERE p_email = '$email'";


  // tenemos que buscar como extraer la id de propietario y luego integrarla

  $resultadouser = $conexion->query($sqluser);
  $filas = $resultadouser->num_rows;
  if ($filas > 0) {
    echo "<script>

     alert('El usuario ya existe');
     window.location = 'index.php';


    </script>";
  }else{
    $sqlusuario = "INSERT INTO mascotas(m_nombre,m_nac,m_rasgos,m_enfermedades,m_habitos, id_prop) VALUES ('$mnombre','$mnacimiento','$mrasgos','$menfermedades','$mhabitos', '$idprop')";

    $resultadousuario = $conexion->query($sqlusuario);
    if ($resultadousuario > 0) {
      echo "<script>

     alert('Registro Existoso');
     window.location = 'index.php';

     </script>";


    }else{
      echo "<script>

     alert('Error al registrarse');
     window.location = 'index.php';

     </script>";
    }
  }
}

?>
```

y en el área de vaciar datos esta este código

```
<?php
                    include("conexion.php");

                    $sql = "SELECT Pro.idpropietarios, Pro.p_nombres, Pro.p_tel, Pro.p_callenumero, Pro.p_colonia, Pro.ciudad, Pro.p_estado, Mas.m_nombre, Mas.m_nac, Mas.m_rasgos, Mas.m_enfermedades, Mas.m_habitos, Mas.id_mascotas FROM propietarios Pro, mascotas Mas WHERE p_email = '$iduser'";


                      $resultado = $conexion->query($sql);
                      while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){

                        echo '

                        <div class="post">
                      <div class="user-block">
                        <img class="img-circle img-bordered-sm" src="img/cacahuate.jpg" alt="user image">
                        <span class="username">
                          <a href="#" style="text-transform: capitalize;">'.$row['m_nombre'].' COD KR'.$row['id_mascotas'].'</a>
                          <a href="#" class="float-right btn-tool"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
                        </span>
                        <span class="description">Actualización - 7:30 PM 12/12/2021</span>
                      </div>
                      <!-- /.user-block -->
                      <p><b>Edad:</b> 10 Años</p>
                      <p><b>Raza:</b> Mixta</p>
                      <p><b>Color</b> '.$row['m_rasgos'].'</p>
                      <b>Enfermedades:</b>
                      <p>
                        '.$row['m_enfermedades'].'
                      </p>
                      <b>Malos habitos:</b>
                      <p>
                        '.$row['m_habitos'].'
                      </p>

                      <p>
                        <a href="#" class="link-black text-sm mr-2"><i class="fas fa-share mr-1"></i> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Reportar Extravio</button></a>
                        <a href="#" class="link-black text-sm"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up mr-1"></i> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Actualizar Datos</button></a>
                        <span class="float-right">
                          <a href="#" class="link-black text-sm">
                            <i class="mr-1"></i>
                          </a>
                        </span>
                      </p>

                      
                    </div>


                        ';
                      }

                     ?>
```

el resultado es este [image: como queda]

Comment: Hola! Estas es StackOverflow en Español! Sería conveniente que expongas la pregunta con un poco más de desarrollo para que se entusiasmen y dediquen su tiempo a responder. Podrás [Editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/513076/edit) tu pregunta cuantas veces necesites.